# Telerik Kendo UI How to Clone an element already initialized

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

In our project, I need to multiply table row. The row which would be copied contains several initialized Kendo UI elements.(AutoComplete, DropDownList,DatePicker.)
When I clone row and change ids of its children, but these copied Kendo UI elements don't work.
Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same query and what I found is that you can make deep copy of the returned JSON object and to assign it where you want after that.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
// Deep copy
var newGrid = jQuery.extend(true, {}, grid);
```

I took the idea from - [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise each  copied component with original components options by renaming
for example

```
$('.row').find('.k-autocomplete').each(function(){
     var kelement = $(this).data('kendoAutoComplete');
     if(kelement)
     {
         var options = kelement.options;
         $('#copiedelement').kendoAutoComplete(options);
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers gave inspire to me; however the "name" option does not  look like related to unique identity of an element. It looks like type of element. ComboBox, AutoComplete, etc. Right?

Comment: oops sorry my mistake. i edited my answer, name is unique id of element, you must change name of copied element with a different name, thats the trick

Comment: as I said before, your answer gave inspire to me. Thanks. I solved this problem using a generic way. Because I have a few Telerik elements in my container which would be copied. I am going to share solve as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after the answer @fatih kiymet advised me, (honestly, it gave inspire to me), I solved the problem using this snippet : http://dojo.telerik.com/@doktoresperanto/EqOHa